# Komodo and program arguments

Tags: perl, komodo

I have a problem with Komodo. In debugging options I have provided
program arguments (a string "21") and then in my main program I have this instruction:

$ik = <STDIN>;

print $ik."L";

**BUT** the program waits for my input "4" in a separate console and doesn't use "21".

[image]

[image]

Comment: The angle brackets `<STDIN>` reads from STDIN, but you are trying to use a command line argument. If you want to use command line argument "21", you can simply do `$ik = shift @ARGV`

Comment: When showing code in a question, you should never use images. Always cut and paste.

Comment: @TLP How can I paste the images present, namely the window containing the number 21 ?

Comment: The better feedback on the pics is to only show relevant part, like the Debugging Options window. Learn to use Alt-PrintScreen, it’s great.

Comment: @user2925716 Like I said, when you are showing *code*, don't use images. In this case, your relevant code was small enough that we understand what you mean without runnable code, but in case you ever ask a more complicated question, showing code with images will not suffice.

Answer (score 1):

The script arguments option that you're filling in passes command-line parameters to your program. These command-line arguments can be accessed inside your program via the `@ARGV` array.

```
my $ik = $ARGV[0];
```

Or

```
# Removes the first argument from @ARGV and returns it
my $ik = shift @ARGV;
```

Or

```
# Outside of a subroutine, shift() used @ARGV by default
my $ik = shift;
```

But that's not how your program expects to receive its input.

```
$ik = <STDIN>;
```

This reads the first record from the `STDIN` filehandle, which is expected to be passed to your program using I/O indirection.

```
$ ./my_program < some_input_file
```

Or piped from the output of another program.

```
$ some_other_process | ./my_program
```

If no redirected input is supplied, your program will, as you have seen, stop and wait for you to supply input.

I don't use Komodo, so I don't know if it has an option to supply input to `STDIN`.